# Screen sharing from Windows to OSX

Tags: windows-7, macos, vnc, screen-sharing

I want to access OSX from my Windows 7 computer.
As far as I know, this can be done easily by clicking "allow VNC viewers" checkbox in OSX.
The problem is that I need to do it on (a lot of) different computers without checking "allow VNC viewers".

The question - is there any way to use the OSX screen share (from windows) without checking "allow VNC viewers" or installing additional software on it.

Comment: Why don't you want to check the "allow VNC viewers" box? Is your objection to the VNC function, or to the mechanics or checking the box, or what? It sounds like you're asking how to allow VNC viewers without allowing VNC viewers, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: OSX screen Sharing is working fine without "allow VNC viewers", but it's limited to OSX to OSX. I need to remote control (a lot of) mac computers that are already setup and don't have this option checked.
OSX screen share works with VNC protocol anyway, so I guess there must be a way to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is probably no, not without a 3rd party app.

If your goal is to share a keyboard and mouse between different systems, you should look into [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/)